# WPF App does not save data after it has been released. How to access the Json file after the app has been released?

Tags: c#, wpf, release

I have a problem with my WPF app.
After I release it with "Create App Package" in VS and then start the app, it does not save the data in the Json file.

Here is the Class I use to save the Trades:

```
 public class JsonSaver : ISaver
{
    #region Property

    /// <summary>
    /// Pfad zur Json Datei (ab Current Directory)
    /// </summary>
    public static string Path = String.Format(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"data\Trades.json");

    #endregion

    #region Methoden

    /// <summary>
    /// Ladet alle Trades von der Json datei(siehe Property "path") in eine ObservableCollection
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>ObservableCollection mit allen Trades</returns>
    public ObservableCollection<Trade> loadTrades()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!File.Exists(Path))
            {
                var w = File.Open(Path, FileMode.Create);
                w.Close();
            }
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(Path))
            {
                string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                if (json == "")
                {
                    return new ObservableCollection<Trade>();
                }
                r.Close();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Trade>>(json);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<Trade>();
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Speicher alle Trades in der Json Datei(siehe Property "path")
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="allTrades">ObservableCollection mit den zu speichernden Trades</param>
    /// <returns>True / False je nach erfolg</returns>
    public bool saveTrades(ObservableCollection<Trade> allTrades)
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(Path, false))
            {
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allTrades);
                w.Write(json);
                w.Close();
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The method "loadTrades" is called everytime the app opens.
The method "saveTrades" is called everytime the app is closed. (MainWindow: Onclosing)
The Json file "Trades.json" is in the correct folder after I install it:
[Directory of the app (found with the Task-Manager)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAS0W.png)

[Json File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R60P7.png)

Everything works when I debug it in VS but not after I release it.

Thanks for the help. If you need more information, feel free to ask.

- Simon

Comment: Does both debug and release executables run?  Check the dates or the executables in both debug and release to see if both have been recompiled since last change.  When running on a different machine you have to publish and run the setup.exe like any commercial software.  Any dlls on the build machine executable folder (debug or release) also have to be in same directory as the executable file.

Comment: Any exception such as `UnauthorizedAccessException` occurs? In general, it is bad idea to save a file in current folder because your app is not always authorized to add/remove a file in that folder. In addition, your use of `String.Format` is wrong. It does nothing.

Comment: Your execution environment is not clear. Also catching an exception without handling it is not recommended. Don't swallow it. It's likely that creating the file or accessing it throws an exception. The executing folder is generally not the best place to store application data. If the user moves the file, the persisted application data won't be available.

Comment: You should use a [SpecialFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=net-6.0#fields). For example the AppData folder for the current user: `string destinationPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`.

Comment: Also if you manage the resource by defining it using the `using` statement, you don't have to close the Stream explicitly.

Comment: StreamReader and StreamWriter offer an async API that you should use.

Comment: Thank you guys for these sulutions. Im going to try them out now and let you guys know if it works.

Comment: You should log errors and exception tons file. That will help you know what went wrong in release mode